# Karma running old test file [AngularJS, Karma, Jasmine, PhantomJS]

Tags: angularjs, phantomjs, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I'm not sure why, but when I run a new Karma test for my AngularJS app I get output from a previous version of my test file.  I'm new to Karma testing so I'm sure I'm missing something somewhere.

> PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 7 0.0.0) Calendar Constructor instantiates a calendar with a year, month, and options FAILED
>   **(This is what I had previously set as output for the this test)**

I have no idea how I'm getting the above output when my test file looks like this.

**test.js**

```
'use strict';

describe('holidays', function () {

    var scope, controller;

    beforeEach(function(){
        module('holiday');
    });

    describe('HolidaysController', function(){

        beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $controller){
            scope = $rootScope;
            controller = $controller('HolidaysController', {
                'vm': scope
            });
        }));

        it('should work', function(){
            expect(vm.tooltips).toBe(false);
        });
    });
});
```

> - Angular version: 1.4.0
> - Karma version: 0.13.22
> - PhantomJS version:
>       2.1.1

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, I had another terminal open that I had previously ran karma in.  After closing both terminals and reopening one the problem was fixed.